# How to position asterisk near to variable name when declaring pointers in C in vscode auto formatting?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, clang-format

Currently if I write `int * ptr;` then auto-formatting would convert it to `int* ptr;` which I don't want. After googling a bit, I found [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) the fix for that. I have to use `PointerAlignment: PAS_Middle`. But I don't know where to add that.

In vscode settings, I tried to add it in `C_Cpp: Clang_format_fallback_style` and `C_Cpp: Clang_format_style`. Neither didn't work. There was no save/apply button in settings, so I hope it would automatically update settings as soon as change it. But nonetheless, whenever I format my C code using Shift+Alt+F, it puts asterisk near to the type!

Comment: You should not use auto-formatting.  It is stupid your module of auto-formatting if it changes the position of the pointer.  Use emacs' electric mode instead.  Electric mode works better in emacs.

Comment: It would go in a .clang-format file with other custom rules. (Yay emacs!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found why it was not working. Because, below it `C_Cpp: Formatting` was set to `vcFormat` and not `clangFormat`. But changing it to `clangFormat` didn't seem to work. Instead it would refuse to format at all!!

Then I had to search below the setting related to this. I found `Pointer Reference Alignment`. But sadly, instead of setting it to `center`, I had to set it to `ignore` since `center` would convert `int *const ptr;` to `int * const ptr;`

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Shawn in comments for pointing me towards `.clang-format` file. I was able to use `clangFormat` now in vscode. But it was inconsistent across different files in different folders of a same project! I don't know if it's fault of clang-format or vscode. For now, I'm falling back to using `vcFormat`.

Comment: Not working. I tried to set right alignment but VS2019 do left alignment always

Answer (score 4):

I solved it in this way:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Code Style > Formatting > Spacing.
At the end of the list from the right window there is a "Pointer/reference alignment" section, select there the option you like.